# Javascript regex currency

Tags: javascript, regex, currency

I'm trying to create a regex that meets the following conditions:

1. 0.01 - true
2. 01.01 - false
3. 122343.10 - true
4. 123,432.10 - false
5. 123 - false
6. 123423.1 - false

I've made the following but its not working as intended

```
^[0\.|1-9\d*\.]\d{2,2}$/
```

Using https://regexr.com/ to test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use this regex:

```
^(?!0\d)\d+\.\d{2}$
```

This uses a negative lookahead in the beginning to handle the requirement that the currency value can't start with zero, if another digit follows immediately afterward.

### Demo

Here is another way of doing this:

```
^(?:0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d{2}$
```

This says to match a zero, followed by nothing by decimal point, or 1-9 if what follows is also another number before the decimal.

Comment: Had to look into what a negative lookahead and non-capture group were. Thanks!

Comment: Your second way fails 1.23

Answer (score 1):

Tim Biegeleisen beat me by a few minutes, but here's another (less sophisticated) solution:

```
(^[0]|^[1-9]+)\.\d{2}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/QJ3YyQ/2

**Edit:** I just realized I missed an edge case. If the digits before the decimal point contained a zero, it wouldn't match.  Here's an updated regex:

```
(^[0]|^[1-9]\d*)\.\d{2}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/QJ3YyQ/4

Comment: This solution was also helpful. Easier to understand. I didn't know you could use parenthesis in such ways. Still have lots more to learn about regex.

Comment: @SILENT The parentheses are called an _alternation_, because they contain two or more possible patterns to use, separated by pipe `|`.